# What is the purpose of "" in setText method?

Tags: android

I have a question about the following code:

`TextView.setText("" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime) / 1000));`

Why is it necessary to include "" in the setText method?

Comment: I don't program android so I can't give a definitive answer, but my hunch is that it is a less verbose way of converting `((System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime) / 1000)` to a string from an integer, so that it can be used in `setText`.

Comment: @JustinL.  Exactly right. (System.currentTimeMillis() -(this.StartTime/1000)).toString() would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I think it's because the developer was too lazy to use the .ToString() Method of Integer.

Answer (score 2):

`setText` only takes Strings, but `((System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime) / 1000)` is a number.

You could always manually cast it with `toString()` or whatever methods you have, but sometimes it's "simpler" to take advantage of the fact that when you add things to a string, the second item is implicitly converted to a string.

That is,

```
"a" + 5
```

will evaluate to

```
"a" + "5"
```

which is

```
"a5"
```

Similarly,

```
"" + 5
"" + "5"
"5"
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that [TextView.setText(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) also exists. So if you just invoke

```
TextView.setText((System.currentTimeMillis() - this.startTime) / 1000);
```

you won't receive a compile time error, but a runtime one when the resource is not found.
If you expect the argument be treated as `String` you have to convert it, one way of doing it is forcing the creation of a `String` by appending to `""`.